# Windows cloud instances for testing open-source project?

Tags: windows, azure, amazon-ec2, scons, buildbot

I work with SCons (www.scons.org), the open-source build tool.  We do test-driven development, and we have a buildbot, but we're always short of Windows buildslaves.  We'd like (in a perfect world) a large collection with different python versions, different compilers, etc.  Is there any free or near-free cloud-based Windows instance we can use with buildbot?  I've looked at Azure and Amazon EC2 -- EC2 micro instances seem like our best bet at the moment, but I'm wondering if there's anything truly free as in beer for open-source project testing.  Anyone else doing anything like this with experience to share?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Free Tier includes 750 hours of Linux or Windows Micro Instances each month for one year. To stay within the Free Tier, use only EC2 Micro instances and this is only for ONE year however with Windows Azure there is no Free instances besides 90 days FREE trial period. To answer your question directly Windows Azure Virtual machine instance are not FREE at however if you decided to choose XS (Extra Small) instances you pay almost the cost of 2 beer per month as shows below:

[image]

Price Calculator: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?scenario=virtual-machines